Smooth curve ellipse in geometry nodes with low resolution
I'm preparing an animation with 5 instances to travel along an ellipse. They must also always face one direction.
I'm able to achieve the instance. However, because the instances are dependent on the resampling of the curve, I'm unfortunately stuck with a rough pentagon shape.
Is there a way to get a smooth elliptical path?


If you want a smooth elliptical path, why don't you resample the curve with more points for the Sample Curve node where you take the Position from? Or why resample it at all when the original curve already is as you want it to be like shown below?


Ah, I see—thank you!
